# LaTeX: only one line at some pages filled, footnotes at wrong pages

Tags: footnotes, page-breaking, bigfoot

I do a critical edition of a medieval german text. For this, I have two kinds of footnotes, using bigfoot.
To my suprise, the layout in the pdf is a mess: No footnote on the first pages bottom (although there are about 8 "explainig" and 9 critical notes at the first page); they are on the second page which is filled only half, the footnotes starting at the middle of the page. This happens on other pages, too.
Some pages have only one line filled, rest is empty space.
I don't see any reason why my text looks like this. Maybe something to do with bigfoot? If I use \newpage at the end of every page, the footnotes are at the place I want them to be. But it should do that alone, doesn't it?
Does anyone of you have any idea?

Here is what I have; if you need more / other things, please let me know.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}

\documentclass [a4paper, ngerman, 12pt] {article}

\newcommand\uo{\raisebox{2\height}{\makebox[0pt][l]{\kern1.3pt\tiny o}}u}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\e}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \check@mathfonts
    \ialign{%
      ##\cr
      \hidewidth\fontsize{\numexpr\ssf@size/1}\z@\bfseries e\hidewidth\cr
      \noalign{\kern.2ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother



\usepackage [utf8] {inputenc}
\usepackage [T1] {fontenc}
\usepackage{helvet}   
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage {babel}
\usepackage[flushmargin]{footmisc}
\usepackage {bigfoot}
\usepackage [right]{lineno}
\usepackage {alphalph}
\usepackage {units}

\parindent0cm
\usepackage {setspace}
\onehalfspace

\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{A}[num]
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{B}[alph]
\makeatletter
\newalphalph{\alphMult}[mult]{\@alph}{26}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\alphMult{\value{footnoteB}}}


\setcounter{page} {28}

\MakePerPage {linenumbers}

\reversemarginpar


\begin {document}
\textbf {Titel}

\begin{pagewiselinenumbers}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

Text\marginpar{1r} Blubb blubb blubb blubb blubb\footnote {Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote} Blubb Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text 

Blubb\footnote {Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote}

[1] Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnote {Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote.}

[2] Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

[3] Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

[4] Item 8 \nicefrac {1}{2} Text Text Text Text Text\footnote {Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote.} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnoteB {Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote \glqq{}Fußnote\grqq{}.}, Text Text Text Text.

[5] <Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnoteB {Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text \glqq{}Zitat Zitat Zitat\grqq{}.} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text TextText Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text;\footnoteB {Blubb Blubb Blubb Blubb.} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnote {Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnoteB {Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote \glqq{}Zitat\grqq{}.} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.>\footnoteB {Nachtrag H\textsubscript{3}}

[6] Item\marginpar {1v} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

[7]  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.

[8] < Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnote {Fußnote.}  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Textext\footnoteB {Fußnote Fußnote.} Text T\e{u}xt  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text T\e{u}xt Text T\e{u}xt Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text T\e{u}xt  Text Text Text Text Text Text>\footnoteB {Fußnote H\textsubscript{3}.}

[9] Text 5\nicefrac {1}{2}  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text t\e{u} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text\footnote{Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote, \textsc{Fußnote}: Fußnote Seitenzahl.} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text, text\footnoteB {Fußnote Fußnote \glqq{}Zitat\grqq{}.}  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text T\e{u}xttext.

[10]  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text. < Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text\footnote {Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote Fußnote, \dag\/ Fußnote Datum.} Text Text Text Text Text Text Te(xt) Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text \textsf{st\uo cke}  Text Text Text Text Text Tex(t) \nicefrac{1}{2} Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.>\footnoteB {Fußnote H\textsubscript{2}.}

[11] Item\marginpar{2r}  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Te(xt)  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Ta\e{u}xt  Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text <Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text.>\footnoteB{Fußnote H\textsubscript{4}.}

\end{pagewiselinenumbers}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code generates complaints about grouping, but fails to demonstrate the problem you describe. Please edit your code so that we can reproduce the problem you want help with.